# Where can I get the exception throwed within the subscribe() method?

Tags: exception, observable, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm using rxAndroid. 
I've read many documents, but still not found the solution, and maybe I missed it,
so please give me a guide.
Here I created an observable that might throw an exception in subscribe method.

```
return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Project>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Project> e) throws Exception {
                e.onNext(projectRepository.readDetails(project.getId()));
                e.onComplete();
            }
        });
```

I use repository pattern to get the project details,
but the problem is all of the repository methods might throw an exception,

```
projectRepository.readDetails(project.getId())
```

And I couldn't find anyway to handle **the exception throwed in the method subscibe()**, **Observer's onError()** will not get any notification of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating an observable manually, you have to catch any exception and pass them to the `onError()` manually:

```
return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Project>() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Project> e) throws Exception {
        try {
            e.onNext(projectRepository.readDetails(project.getId()));
            e.onComplete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            e.onError(ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively you should be able to use `fromCallable()` to avoid having to create the observable manually:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> projectRepository.readDetails(project.getId()));
```

This will signal `onError()` if the call should fail.